# Getting the PERCENTRANK.INC in PowerPIvot/DAX

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

I have been tasked with converting a a worksheet from standard Excel into PowerPivot. However, I have hit a roadblock with the PERCENTRANK.INC function which is not available in DAX. I have come close to replicating it using a formula, but there are definite differences in the calculation.

Does anyone know how Excel calculates PERCENTRANK.INC()?

```
Formula in cell D2: =(COUNT($A$2:$A$10)-B2)/(COUNT($A$2:$A$10)-1)
Formula in cell B2: =RANK.EQ(A2,$A$2:$A$10,0)
Formula in cell C2: =PERCENTRANK.INC($A$2:$A$10,A2)
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Have you seen all the answer here? https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/PERCENTRANK-Inclusive/m-p/81208

Comment: Hi QHarr - I did see that post (see comment below on ashleedawg's answer). What I am really looking for here is a clear understanding of how Microsoft calculates PERCENTRANK.INC() and what are the difference between that and the formula in ashleedawgs answer. That post did however have and proposed solution from OwenAuger, but I can't make heads or tails of his logic in order to replicate for my use case.

Comment: Did you try implementing Owen's solution as a function in Dax? How did result compare?

Comment: To be honest, I got lost following the logic. I haven't used vars in DAX before and was unsure why the downloaded workbook had two tables in it? If I understood what was going on, than I was hoping to replicate.

Comment: Additionally, if you take Owen's test numbers (1.0,1.5,2.0... 10) and use Excel's PERCENTRANK.INC() formula against them, you come up with different answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Edit:

It's seems strange to me that there are so many "standard" ways to calculate `PERCENTRANK` that has have slightly different results.

Using your example of your 9-number set of `1,2,3,4,4,6,7,8,9`, depending on which "authority" I used, the *third* value (`3`) had a Percent Rank of `25.0%, 27.0%, 27.8% or 30.0%`.

Obviously we'll go with the one that gives your desired result, matching `PERCENTRANK.INC`.

> ### *`PERCENTRANK.INC` is calculated as:*
>
> ### [count of values lower than the given value]
>
> ### ÷
>
> ### [count of all values in the set excluding the given value]

so, if our range of `1,2,3,4,4,6,7,8,9`is in `A1:A9`, we could use this formula in `B1`:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$9,"<"&A1)/(COUNT($A$1:$A$9)-1)
```

...and copy or "fill" it down for results:

```
0.0%, 12.5%, 25.0%, 37.5%, 37.5%, 62.5%, 75.0%, 87.5%, 100.0%
```

---

### Original Answer

> I think you just want to calculate the `PERCENTRANK` for current row
>   value. Based on the logic for `PERCENTRANK`, we can add a `RANK` column in
>   table and achieve same logic based on this column.
>
> [image: pic1]
>
> **Create a `Rank` column.**
>
> ```
> Rank = RANKX(Table6,Table6[Value])
> ```
>
> Then **create the `PctRank` based on the `Rank` column.**
>
> ```
> PctRank = (COUNTA(Table6[Name])-Table6[Rank])/(COUNTA(Table6[Name])-1)
> ```
>
> [image: pic2]

<sup>([Source](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/PERCENTRANK-Inclusive/m-p/81208))</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did see those instructions, and that is where I got my formula from used in column D in my example above. However, I still get differences with your PowerBi approach, and Excel's calculation using PERCENTRANK.INC(). Not quite sure as to why, but assuming that there is something else going on the Microsoft's calculation that the formula misses...

Comment: now you have me thinking about this.....I know that 38% = 63%-23% (The next highest and next lowest after the tied numbers.)  That would be fairly straightforward to figure out with a VBA loop but you can't use VBA in Power Pivot either, can you?

Comment: @Chris - Hooray, I got it figured!  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: This is awesome ashleedawg! Thanks so much. You saved my bacon :)

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for sharing the [complete solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49354373) to [help others in the future](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pay_it_forward)!

Comment: Actually found there was one other part to the formula. PERCENTRANK.INC() is only calculated to 3 decimal places, rounding down. Have adjusted the DAX answer to suit.

Answer (score 1):

For reference here is the DAX formula based off ashleedawg's answer which includes ignoring cells with no values in them.

```
=ROUNDDOWN(COUNTROWS(FILTER('Lookup_Query','Lookup_Query'[Entrances]<EARLIER('Lookup_Query'[Entrances]) && ISBLANK('Lookup_Query'[Entrances])=FALSE()))/(COUNTROWS(FILTER('Lookup_Query',ISBLANK('Lookup_Query'[Entrances])=FALSE()))-1),3)
```

Comment: Small modification. Found that using BLANK() in the FILTER() actually excludes cells with 0 in them (which is kinda weird because ISBLANK() doesn't). I've updated the DAX answer again.