# why am I getting a "single value for column cannot be determined" error when using the "EARLIER" function?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm getting the "a single value for column cannot be determined" error in Power BI when using the EARLIER function.

I've tried using code from this post: [Getting the PERCENTRANK.INC in PowerPIvot/DAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49341558/getting-the-percentrank-inc-in-powerpivot-dax)

I've also googled the EARLIER function plus other methods to avoid blanks, hoping this was the cause. Still get the error.

Finally, I tried the original solution in the post above; still get the same error:

```
RankAwards = RANKX('HRO_Table_current','HRO_Table_current'[HM31_AWARD_AMOUNT])

AwardsPercRank =
COUNTROWS (
    FILTER (
        'HRO_Table_current',
        'HRO_Table_current'[HM31_AWARD_AMOUNT]
            < EARLIER ( 'HRO_Table_current'[HM31_AWARD_AMOUNT] )
            && ISBLANK ( 'HRO_Table_current'[HM31_AWARD_AMOUNT] ) = FALSE ()
    )
)
    / (
        COUNTROWS (
            FILTER (
                'HRO_Table_current',
                ISBLANK ( 'HRO_Table_current'[HM31_AWARD_AMOUNT] ) = FALSE ()
            )
        ) - 1
    )
```

Expected Results: similar to what one would get using PERCENTRANK in Excel.

Actual Results: error mentioned before "a single value for column cannot be determined"

Comment: Is "AwardsPercRank" a measure or a calculated column?

Comment: It's a calculated column.

Answer (score 0):

Give this one try

```
RankAwards = RANKX('HRO_Table_current','HRO_Table_current'[HM31_AWARD_AMOUNT])

VAR FIRTVALOR =

CALCULATE(
  COUNTROWS(HRO_Table_current);
  HRO_Table_current[HM31_AWARD_AMOUNT]< EARLIER(HRO_Table_current[HM31_AWARD_AMOUNT]);
  ISBLANK (HRO_Table_current[HM31_AWARD_AMOUNT] ) = FALSE ()
        )



VAR SECONDVALOR=      
      CALCULATE(
          COUNTROWS(HRO_Table_current);
          ISBLANK(HRO_Table_current[HM31_AWARD_AMOUNT]) = FALSE()
               )

RETURN((FIRTVALOR / SECONDVALOR)-1)
```

What are you trying to do with RANKX, i think the 2nd valor most be an expression, i'm not sure what you're trying to do with RANKX statement.